# Python script - get installed packages in other virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm creating a virtual environment during runtime using virtualenv.create_environment. If this env was already created I skip the installation, but would like to check and see if a certain package is installed. Right now I'm running a command activating the env and `pip list`.

My question is if I can to import the pip from the virtual env and `pip.get_installed_distributions()`?

Comment: What happens when you just try what you recommend here?

Comment: I get the packages from the environment my script runs from because I cannot activate the new virtual env and run pip.get_installed_distribution() at the same time